# Simulating a specific circuit on LTspice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, thevenin

[image: The Circuit]

[image]

Because I wanted to find the Voc and the Isc (of the load) for the circuit to calculate Rth, I decided to put the resistance as 99999999 to find Voc, and then 0 to find Isc.

The problem here is I have no idea how to edit the current controlled voltage source to reflect current passing through the resistor. The Youtube tutorials I found online only teach the methods to connect the CCVS to a current source, but not to a resistor.

I tried to put the Value of the dependent source as R1 and Value2 as 3 but LTspice tells me that R1 is an unknown value.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem here is I have no idea how to edit the current controlled
>   **voltage source** to reflect current passing through the resistor.

To begin with, you need a current dependent **current source** and not a current dependent voltage source. Or you can choose an arbitrary source.

Your input to the source is ill-defined by "R1". See how this example works: -

[image]

You need a dependant current source (B1 above or H for a CDCS) and the variable that is your input is I(R1): -

[image]

As you should be able to see, Vin (left) is going to be 1 volt and Vout (right) is going to be 10 volts.

Answer (score 0):

Spice only allows measuring current through voltage sources. So instead of specifying R1 as the current-controlling device, specify V1 instead. The current is the same through both components anyway.

[image: Suggested properties for the CCVS]

If you ever find yourself in need of a current through a device that is not a voltage source, just add a voltage source of 0V in series. This is also the "official" method suggested by the people that created Spice 3f5 (the precursor LTspice).

> zero valued voltage sources may be inserted into the circuit for the purpose of measuring current

Link: [Berkeley Spice website](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/UserGuide/elements_fr.html)

Comment: Many thanks, Sven and Andy.

I have another question, however. What if I need the potential difference of a resistor for a voltage dependent voltage source?

Comment: Then you can use a voltage controlled source, which is a 4 terminal device. Ie. you can connect the controlling voltages. Glad to help!